# Pulling a Git repository brings different files

Tags: git, github, push, git-commit

We are working in a project which code is hosted in Github. At some point the main branch ***master*** had to be rolled back to a certain commit. We did that by locally rolling back to the commit, then forcing a push to the remote.

That seemed to work well, and checking directly in Github shows that the files were all rolledback, and the folders expected to dissapear did, which is correct.

Then I deleted my local ***master*** in order to fetch the new one. I did so by running:

```
git checkout someotherbranch
git branch -D master
git fetch --all
git checkout master
```

Some files actually seem correct, that is rolled back to the specified commit, however some folders with the files inside remain there. Also some other file, an HTML file, didn't correctly rolled back.

Is there any step I am missing?

Comment: When you check that html file on github, on master, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct! I assume there is some kind of local cache?

Comment: Try recloning and verifying your fresh clone. There shouldn't be a local cache.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually missing one step:

```
git reset --hard
```

So the unwanted local files would be gone and make the local branch perfectly match the remote one